# More than one blocks of infinitely repeating digits in a number

Tags: infinity, number-systems

> **TL;DR:** Meaning of these types of numbers: $1.2\overline{34}5\overline{67}$;

There exist (rational) numbers that are non-terminating, but have a repeating form of digits (e.g., $ 1.2\overline{34} $).

1. What I want to know is: does having 2 block of repeating digits make sense? My intuition says, "Why not?"; but my logic cannot comprehend, for example, when the 5 in the above example would occur and how you could, say, minus it from another number or w/e.
2. If so, can the resulting things be called numbers? What sort of numbers then? They wouldn't be rational, and probably not real; maybe we need a new (or an existing esoteric) system to be able to make them mean something and manipulate them.

**Edit:** Coming to think about it, another question that needs to be answered before considering this one is what is the meaning of numbers like $1.2\overline{34}5$. When is the $5$ reached? How would you go about trying to cancel that 5 or the repeating digits by minusing something?

**Disclaimer:** Excuse me if this question:

- **has been already answered.** I had not known the correct terminology and had not been able to to find anything on Google or MSE.
- **does not make sense:** As mentioned before, this may be because I am not able to express myself clearly.
- **is not an answerable one or is irrelevant:** If the answer is indeed "No," then I'd like a reason why so. After all, a lot of stuff was incomprehensible until systems to describe it were *invented*.

**Update:** Seems this sort of a question had been [asked before right here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/what-are-the-implications-of-the-discovery-of-the-kalle-numbers), albeit by someone way more self-aggrandizing than me ;) [causing it to get deleted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411/what-are-the-implications-of-the-discovery-of-the-kalle-numbers). If you still want to see a copy of the question, [check it out on the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120120013843/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14879/what-are-the-implications-of-the-discovery-of-the-kalle-numbers).

**Verdict:** With no proper definition, rules for manipulation and useful model that they represent; these sort of numbers remain undefined and useless.

Comment: While the numbers you're looking for don't really make sense, the *idea* of a repeating block, and then some things, and then another repeating block isn't nonsense - it just doesn't match up with standard decimal notation. See my answer to a different question for an application of that idea to a different sort of number system http://math.stackexchange.com/a/483582/26369

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You edit, with $1.2\overline{34}5$ shows the problem well.  The normal way to read this would be that the $34$ repeats forever and you never get to the $5$, in which case it is the nicely rational number $1\frac {116}{495}$.  I wrote the below thinking you were looking at numbers like in the first line, where the repetition alternates between the $34$ and the $56$ with some changeable digit between them.

You can certainly conceive of numbers of the form $1.x34x56x34x56x34x56$, where the $x$'s anc represent any digit, not all the same.  If they were all the same, we could just view $x34x56$ as one repeating set of digits and it is a rational like we know and love.  If there is no pattern in the $x$'s, the number will be real irrational.  Any given one of them can be operated with like any other real number.

Comment: So are you saying that it is not a number? Why can't you remove the 5 by minusing $0.\bar{0}5$?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by $1.2\overline{34}5$.  We have a definition of $1.2\overline{34}$ as a limit:  it is $1.2+\frac {34}{10^3}+\frac{34}{10^5}+\dots$  The question is how does the $5$ change that? Since the $34$'s go on forever, you don't get to the $5$, so it doesn't matter.  In that spirit, you would never get to the $67$ in the original problem, so it is the same number.  I read it differently, finding a way to pay attention to the $67$, but it is on you to say what you really mean.  In a sense, I responded to $1.2\overline{34x56x}$.  If that is not what you meant, say so.

Comment: That is not what I meant; I had meant an infinitely repeating block of digits, followed by **another** infinitely repeating set of digits. But what I think _you're_ trying to say is that since anything after the first set of infinitely repeating digits is never really reached, they are negligible and useless to consider; am I ryt?

Comment: That is correct.  A good way to think of an infinite decimal is as a series.  If the digits are $d_i, i\in \Bbb N$, the number is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac {d_i}{10^i}$.  This is a convergent series and converges to the value.  Since the first repeat provides all the digits you need, you never get past it, so nothing else matters.

Comment: Well, I guess that sums it all up then. With no proper definition, rules for manipulation and useful model that they represent; these sort of numbers remain undefined and useless.